# Understanding average velocity formula?

Tags: calculus

This is an example in my book for average velocity (sorry I can't get \le to work).

$$s(t)=\frac12t^2-\frac1{12}t^3, 0\le t\le4$$

where $s$ is measure in miles and $t$ is measured in minutes. Approximate the velocity at time $t=2$.

My question is the solution below. Does the $s(4)-s(2)$ mean replace the $t$ in the above equation?

Averaging over the 2 minutes from $t=2$ to $t=4$,

$$V_{avg}=\frac{s(4)-s(2)}{4-2}\approx\frac{2.6667-1.3333}{2}\approx.6667 mile/minute\approx40mph$$

Comment: It looks correct to me.

Comment: Yes, it means replace $t$ with the numbers listed.

Comment: @bob.sacamento Thanks! I wish the people who wrote these books used some common sense (or at least one or two step-by-step examples)

Comment: @xerxes2985  Yeah, I know what you mean.  :-)

Comment: @xerxes2985 If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's correct.

An important observation about **terminology**: in physics is common to distinguish between speed (that is a scalar quantity) and velocity (that is a vector).

Thus in this case the quantity should be indicated as "**average speed**".

Note that it's not only a matter of definition. For example, think at a **circular path.** After one lap your average velocity is zero but average speed is positive.

Comment: You've not only helped me out to visualize this, but I am going to thank you ahead of time for answering a question when I take physics soon :)